# Entity Framework check database compatible with model

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I have project with code first migrations. And I was stuck in situation, when **Add-Migration** throws an Exception. So I decided to use it with **-IgnoreChanges** and write migration code myself.

Now I want to check whether the database after the custom migration is compatible with the model. All I found is **CompatibleWithModel** method, but it compares the model with the schema stored in the **__MigrationHistory** table, and not with the schema of the database itself, so in my case it is useless.

EF 6.1.3

Comment: What was the exception message before you ignored it :)

Comment: "Sequence contains more than one element". I think I got this one because I used a custom model convention, and then disabled it.

Comment: Adding a migration with -IgnoreChanges just tells EF to do the snapshot of the model without changing the database (no Up() code generated). Then you do update-database and the migration is recorded in __MigrationHistory and CompatibleWithModel will be true. I am not sure what you mean by 'Custom Migration'. Did you write your own Up() code or do something else?

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own Up() code.